# Want to install Ubuntu on Intel x86 32-bit.

Tags: partitioning

Want to install Ubuntu on Intel x86 32-bit. Machine has MS Vista (wish to maintain) is disconnected from Internet. Which procedure should I follow? Which file to download on a USB, possibly?

Comment: If Vista, it probably is a 64 bit system. Only if less than 2GB of RAM may 32 bit be better. But since older system you may find Ubuntu too heavy and need a lighterweight flavor. Lightweight flavors
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu mate, Budgie
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors